# Cartoon series about a world-saving agent, who is an Indiana Jones and James Bond mixture

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I am looking for a cartoon TV series from my childhood:

1. The show is an animated television series for children, named after the main character, if I recall correctly.
2. The main character is a (secret?) agent, described as a mixture of Indiana Jones and James Bond by the creator. Not so much in looks, but more in the type of adventures he is involved with.
3. The main character wears a black shirt and a red jacket and has black hair.
4. The main character has a sidekick named "Max" (?) who is a large, muscular man with red hair and a yellow shirt.
5. Among the enemies, there's an Asian man who clones himself and transfers his consciousness into a clone when he dies.
6. The show involves time travel - at least, in the intro there appears a dinosaur.
7. The show is ~20 years old, meaning it was aired around or before 2003.
8. I believe the show is American-made, but the main character had a French name, I think.
9. The setting is "today", but with a ton of fantasy and sci-fi elements.

Comment: *go-go-gadedt, google.* - whoops, I forgot to hold down the *a* key while it was booting. This could take a minute....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds a lot like *[Bob Morane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Morane_(1998_TV_series))*, a 1998 cartoon series. The main character was a super-spy, much in the James Bond mould (but in truth I don't see much resemblance to Indiana Jones), based on a French adventure book series. He indeed wore a black shirt with a red jacket, and had black hair.

[image: Screenshot of the title character of the "Bob Morane" animated series]

He had a sidekick, who was a big muscular man with red hair and a yellow shirt, but rather than being called "Max" he was named Bill Ballantine.

Many of the episodes are available on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPnSzwzam6A), and In the intro, a dinosaur does indeed appear.

Comment: Boah, yes! So nice, thank you! I got a lot of details wrong, but you nailed it! Regarding Indiana Jones connection: I read an interview with the creator once and he said that he envisioned a mixture of Bond and Jones. I see the connection, because - unlike Bond - Bob is also in lost temples and such a lot and deals with (more or less) magical things.